# Twig how to get html between two tags to a service

Tags: symfony, tags, twig, twig-extension

I want some simple twig tags that allow me to do the following:

```
{% customtag 'name' %}
  <div> some html </div>
{% endcustomtag %}
```

And then get that html inside of a service.

I have tried doing this myself but when I finally have al the data that I want inside of my NodeVisitor I can't seem to get it to my service. If I inject it and call a method on it it never gets executed. It only gets called if I try to clear my cache from my command line.

Can somebody please give some insight?

Comment: You question is not enough to understand your requirement. However you can define your  customtag  inside your base.html.twig like you described  and use anywhere.

Comment: Again, I want to simulate how {% block %} works.

I want to grab html between two custom tags, which worked fine. So I have this html inside of my NodeVisitor, but the question is, how do I get it inside my service now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can access your extensions from Twig_Template.

So you can do:

```
$compiler->write('$this->extensions[')
  ->string('your_extension')
  ->write(']->getService()->someFunction();')
  ->raw(PHP_EOL);
```

in your twig node. And then in your extension you should just inject the service and return it in the `getService` method.